# what is wrong in the call of this simple haskell test function

Tags: haskell

Been a loooong time since I wrote code in Haskell, so while I do know quite a bit about it (from previous experience) it is slowly comming back. I am not sure why the following snippet does not want to run. Could you point out please.

```
convChar::Char->Int
convChar chr
 |chr == 'A'    =0
 |otherwise     =28

main = do
convChar 'A'
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`main` function is an entry point of a program and it **must** be of type `IO ()`, but you are defining it in terms of function with `Int` type. So, you should transform `Int` to `IO ()`, that is why you need a function with type `Int -> IO()`. It may print the given number to *stdout*, or just sleep the program for a given duration. You could find out such functions using [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+IO+%28%29).

Note, that `print` function has `Show a => a -> IO ()` type, so, it is better to search this function by name, not by type `Int -> IO ()`.

So, if you want to print the result of your function, you should rewrite `main` function in the following way:

```
main = print $ convChar 'A'
```

Just a note: if you are not familiar with `$` function, you could use brackets, to define the order of execution

```
main = print (convChar 'A')
```

But using `$` makes your code cleaner

Comment: Thanks. I know how to use $. :)) I am looking back at old code and I am seeing indeed that they all start with a print $ ..... statement.